# How to execute commands with double quotes (net start "windows search") using python 'os' module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I execute simple command like "net start", I am getting output successfully as shown below.

Python script:

```
import os

def test():
    cmd = ' net start  '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    print output
test()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\service>python test.py
These Windows services are started:

   Application Experience
   Application Management
   Background Intelligent Transfer Service
   Base Filtering Engine
   Task Scheduler
   TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper


The command completed successfully.

C:\Users\test\Desktop\service>
```

But When I execute long commands (for example : "net start "windows search") I am **NOT** getting any output.

Python script:

```
import os

def test():
    cmd = ' net start "windows search"  '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    print output

test()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\service>python test.py


C:\Users\test\Desktop\service>
```

I have tried "net start \"windows search\" ". also. But same issue.

Can anyone guide me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

> *Deprecated since version 2.6:* This function is obsolete. Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Check especially the [*Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section.

```
subprocess.Popen(['net', 'start', 'windows search'], ...)
```